# google api developer console login error

Tags: google-api

Whenever I go to http://code.google.com/apis/console , it redicts me to a almost blank page with nothing but text "30" on the page.

After view source I see

```
<html><head><title>404 (Not Found)</title><style type="text/css">
    body {
      white-space: pre;
      font-family: Monaco, "Liberation Mono", Courier, monospace;
      font-size: .75em;
    }
</style></head><body>30</body></html>
```

It happens over and over and after I delete cookies it still happens shortly after I login again.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the site is trying to redirect you to an old project that you deleted and no longer exists. 
check the URL it should be something like

```
this = console.developers.google.com/project/{ProjectNumber}/?auth... etc.
```

delete the `[project/{ProjectNumber}/]` part you should have 
something like

```
this =  console.developers.google.com/?auth... etc.
```

I don't know why this happens but that did it for me hope it helps